# set up views using panels in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-panels

How do i set up a view to show up in my drupal panel. I have the view created. I have assigned it to the panel. However what do i put in under the "context type" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you "assigned" your view to the panel. In the Panel editing screen you should see a section labelled "Content" just above "Layouts". The content screen is where you select which Views to add to your panel.

Regarding, what a "context" is, in [Panels terminology](http://www.angrydonuts.com/panels-what-is-context), it's a wrapper around significant objects that your panels are aware about and they allow you to show your panels in different ways, ie contexts. For example, I needed to pass arguments to my Panel so I had to add each one as a context.

If you have a few minutes I would recommend you go through this [intro video on Panels](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-panels).

Comment: I am having issue while configuring the view for the panel views pane. I am using the same view in multiple view panes, however it displays different output.

Comment: what kind of different output are you seeing? could it be you haven't specified a sort that makes it seem different?